# How to clear Silverlight MediaElement's cache

Tags: silverlight, caching, mediaelement

I'm playing videos with the Silverlight [`MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980132%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This component uses some internal cache for played video fragments.

Is there any way to clear this cache manually or programmatically? I have an annoying bug, that is reproducing only when there is no cache exists, and it's hard to fix it, because I need to find a fresh video every time for test.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but here's a suggestion: using the private mode of your browser could do the trick.

Simply close and re-open your private window between each test